# How to read and save prompt information when user clicks inside prompt text after typing in it

Tags: javascript, html

I need a function that save what the user types inside the prompt text when they click inside the prompt.
The function must be activated when the user clicks inside the prompt after writing on it, and then will store the information typed in a variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We do not write code for free ... well we sort of do, but why don't you take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. Once you've done this, please re-visit your question and try to improve it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since SO isn't a code writing service, I would checkout [mcve] as you are expected to have made an attempt at coding it yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hello so if you want to store the text that user type in prompt you cant store the prompt function in variables like the exam:

```js
const userInput = window.prompt("Type something:");
console.log(userInput);
```

Now After user click on OK button the value will print in the console

Comment: Actually, what i need is something different.
Imagine you type something in the search box in Google, you don't clink in the search button yet. 
And then you run the code in console and you click inside the prompt of search, the function will read the data you type inside the prompt text.

I was looking for something that will work in any text prompt in the web.

Comment: in javascript, you have to wait for the prompt function to finish and after that, you run another function but in your case, you don't have to use the prompt you can create an input with a custom design and implement your idea. if you want some help send to me on Instagram: haider_fadell